# How can I prevent users from writing things inside of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'd like my Windows Form ComboBox to only allow users to select from available options and not write things in.

Is there a property somewhere I'm missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList`.